# list all left for all dates and ids nulls SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

Hi i have a problem with a query i want to do
the tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE `lista` (
  `job` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`job`)
);

CREATE TABLE `updatesjobs` (
  `job` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `odate` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `runtime` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `endtime` varchar(20) NOT NULL
);
```

the table updatesjobs doesnt have jobs for all odates

if i do this

```
select l.nombre,l.job,u.odate 
  from lista l 
  left 
  join updatesjobs u
    on l.job=u.job 
   and u.odate = "20200615"
```

it appears the information

```
01. text01  JOB1    20200615
02. text02  JOB2    NULL
03. text03  JOB3    20200615
04. text04  JOB4    NULL    
05. text05  JOB5    20200615
06. text06  JOB6    NULL
```

the information appear as it should be but i dont want to filter by date

i need to appear for all dates the dates dont have a job executed

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Can you give a small example of the data in each table and what you are expecting for a response?  An example on a site like [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) would be great!

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your question, you can enumerate all available dates in `updatejobs`, `cross join` the results with jobs from table `lista`, and finally use `not exists` to identify the missing rows in `updatejobs`:

```
select l.nombre, l.job, d.odate 
from lista l 
cross join (select distinct o.date from updatejobs) d
where not exists (
    select 1 from updatesjobs u where u.job = l.job and u.odate = d.odate
)
```

Comment: Hi its better if i add an example how i need the data returned